# postgresql where does the output of pg_dump go

Tags: database, postgresql, command-line, backup, pg-dump

I am trying to backup a db of postgresql and I want to use `pg_dump` command.
I tried :

```
psql -U postgres
postgres-# pg_dump test > backup.sql
```

But I don't know where the output file goes.
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Why don't you do it then run `find / -name backup.sql`

Comment: For Mac Os Kindly check this answer [here][1] is well explained.

  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50823671/4683950

Comment: Keep in mind that you should not be running the pg_dump command from within the postgres command line if you are trying to write to a file. Run it as mentioned below in [https://stackoverflow.com/a/24931100/10027828](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24931100/10027828). If you simply run `pg_dump -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgresUser dbName > backup.sql` then the `backup.sql` file will be saved to the directory you are running the command from (so if you are in a Linux terminal simply enter `ls` to see the directory contents).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Go to command prompt and directory postgresql\9.3\bin.

**Example**

.

```
..
    c:\Program files\postgresql\9.3\bin> pg_dump -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres test > D:\backup.sql
...
```

After above command enter User "postgres" password and check `D:\` drive for `backup.sql` file

Comment: ^^' what if you don't have a D: drive ?

Answer (score 72):

I'm late to this party, but I feel that none of the answers are really correct. Most seem to imply that `pg_dump` writes a file somewhere. It doesn't. *You* are sending the output to a file, and *you* told the shell where to write that file.

In your example `pg_dump test > backup.sql`, which uses the `plain` or SQL format, the `pg_dump` command **does not store** any file anywhere. It just sends the output to `STDOUT`, which is usually your screen, and it's done.

But in your command, you also told your shell (Terminal, Command prompt, whatever) to redirect STDOUT to a file. This has nothing to do with `pg_dump` but is a standard feature of shells like Bash or cmd.exe.

You used `>` to redirect STDOUT to a file instead of the screen. And you gave the file name: "backup.sql". Since you didn't specify any path, the file will be in your current directory. This is probably your home directory, unless you have done a `cd ...` into some other directory.

In the particular case of `pg_dump`, you could also have used an alternative to the `> /path/to/some_file` shell redirection, by using the [`-f some_file` option](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/app-pgdump.html):

> -f file
>  --file=file
>
> Send output to the specified file. This parameter can be omitted for file based output formats, 
>   in which case the standard output is used.

So your command could have been `pg_dump test -f backup.sql`, asking pg_dump to write directly to that file.

But in any case, you give the file name, and if you don't specify a path, the file is created in your current directory. If your prompt doesn't already display your current directory, you can have it shown with the `pwd` command on Unix, and `cd` in Windows.

Comment: TLDR (for me): Running `pg_dump my_database` didn't create a file, it just output the content of my database in my terminal. I should have piped the output to a file, for example: `pg_dump my_database > backup.sql`

Answer (score 26):

In my situation (PostgreSQL 9.1.21, Centos 6.7), the command

```
runuser -l postgres -c 'pg_dump my_database > my_database.sql'
```

saved the file here:

```
/var/lib/pgsql/my_database.sql
```

Not sure if that is true for other Linux dists, CentOS and/or pgl versions. According to [the answer post by the asker of this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/235622/where-my-postgresql-database-backup-is-stored-after-run-pg-dump), this is true, but other users said the backup file was in the current directory (a situation different of most people reading this thread, for obvious reasons). Well, I hope this can help other users with the same problem.

P.s.: if that's not the path for your situation, you can try (in Linux) to find it using the below command (as stated by @Bohemian in the comments of this question), but this can take a while:

```
find / -name 'my_database.sql'
```

**EDIT:** I tried to run the analogous command in Ubuntu 12.04 (it works on Ubuntu 18.04):

```
sudo -u postgres pg_dump my_database > my_database.sql
```

And in this case the file was saved in the current directory where I ran the command! So both cases can happen in Linux, depending of the specific dist you are working

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04 this command dump the file just where you execute it. It works perfect.

Comment: sudo -u postgres pg_dump s2s_mall > my_database.sql worked for me, I can see DB_bkp on current Dir... Thanks!!!!

Comment: @Brian Hellekin: " I hope this can help other users with the same problem." Yes, it helped me! I am on Ubuntu 18.04 and found at /var/lib/pgadmin/storage/my username. Thanks much! p.s.

Answer (score 8):

For Linux default dump path is:

```
/var/lib/postgresql/
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are not specifying fully qualified paths, like:

`pg_dump your_db_name > dbdump`

then in *Windows* it stores dumps in current user's home directory. I.e.:

`C:\Users\username`

Comment: Same in Ubuntu: running pg_dump -U postgres dbname > dbfile from under a root resulted into root/dbfile

Answer (score 4):

If you use linux (except centos)

```
sudo su - postgres
pg_dump your_db_name > your_db_name.sql
cd /var/lib/postgresql
ls -l
```

Here your'll see your_db_name.sql file

Answer (score 3):

In pgadmin 4 for a Mac, assuming dump is successful you can click on "More Details" you will see a box that says "Running command:" in that box you will see /Applications/pgAdmin 4.app/Contents/SharedSupport/pg_dump --file "path/to/file" where path to file is the destination of storage.

Answer (score 2):

After doing

```
psql -U postgres
```

Using the command

```
\! pg_dump -U postgres humaine > C:\Users\saivi\OneDrive\Desktop\humaine_backup1.sql
```

The output file would go where the path at the right is specified

Answer (score 1):

In the server (Ubundu/Centos) the path of backup file will be
*/var/lib/pgadmin/storage/*

Answer (score 1):

```
$ pg_dump --dbname="postgresql://[username]:[password]@[host]:[port]/[db_name]" -F t -O -x -R > file.sql
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Comment: including the full connection string (username, password, port, etc.) was extremely useful to me

Answer (score 1):

Just open pgAdmin, right-click your db and select "backup...". Specify filepath there.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the OS specification.

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
```

I am using following command to take the backup of postgresql database.

```
pg_dump -U postgres -Fc <db_name> > /var/lib/postgresql/backup-20230123.dump
```

If storage file path has been provided explicitly, in that case, the database dump will be generated to that place only.

For windows, provide folder path where you want to download the dump.