# Can't seem to generate pg_dump data to output file

Tags: postgresql, command-line-interface, pg-dump

I know this has been asked before and I've read plenty of stuff, [such as this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24930923/postgresql-where-does-the-output-of-pg-dump-go), but somehow can't get this working.

I have the following command, being run on a Postgres Docker container, which successfully generates a dump of my DB - but straight to the terminal (STDOUT).

```
docker exec -it db pg_dump -h example.com -U postgres postgres
```

Now, if I redirect STDOUT like so:

```
docker exec -it db pg_dump -h example.com -U postgres postgres > file.txt
```

...it then hangs, and nothing happens - presumably because it gets stuck on the password prompt, and there's nowhere for it to show that.

I did try to use a `.pgpass` file instead, but I don't know how to associate that with the `pg_dump` operation (the `.pgpass` merely living in the same directory didn't seem to result in it being used.) Contents as follows:

```
example.com:5432:postgres:postgres:12345
```

...and then:

```
docker exec -it db pg_dump
```

...which simply complains that role "root" does not exist.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: As the documentation loudly explains, `.pgpass` is in your home directory. You forgot the `-U` option and the database name in your final dump attempt. Never run something like that as root user!

Comment: Thanks for your comment. which wasn't overly friendly in tone. Why do I need `-U` (user) and database name if both of those things are also specified in the `.pgpass` file? And home directory as in... `C:\Users\<user>`?

Comment: 1) Because a `.pgpass` file can have multiple combinations of user/port/database/host/password and the only way to determine which is the appropriate one is by explicitly supplying the correct parameters. 2) As to the locations it is spelled out here [pgpass](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/libpq-pgpass.html)

Comment: I didn't mean to be unfriendly - to make up I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html) explains,

> The file `.pgpass` in a user's home directory can contain passwords to be used if the connection requires a password (and no password has been specified otherwise). [...]
>
> On Unix systems, the permissions on a password file must disallow any access to world or group; achieve this by a command such as `chmod 0600 ~/.pgpass`.

The password file contains the password *for a specific host, port, user and database*, so you have to specify those in your connection attempt. The client library then takes the password from the corresponding entry in the password file.